# How to access a struct in Cython that has been in a list as a C struct

Tags: cython

How to access a struct in Cython that has been in a list as a C struct, not as a dictionary. It appears that whenever I pass a C struct in a python list and retrieve it from the list it is wrapped as a dict. Even in my cython code. How can I directly access the c struct.
The example below creates an error. If it wouldn't my problem was solved.

optimization_functions.pyx

```
ctypedef struct sGrail:
    int age
    char* text

ctypedef sGrail Grail

def cythontest(char* a):
    cdef sGrail grail
    grail.age = 5
    grail.text = a
    return [grail]

def print_grail(grailarray):
    print type(grailarray[0])
    grail = grailarray[0]
    print grail.age
    grail.age = 99
    print grailarray[0]
    print "age here should be 99 not 5"
```

start.py

```
import optimization_functions

grailarray = optimization_functions.cythontest('test')
print grailarray
optimization_functions.print_grail(grailarray)
```

Comment: The conversion happens when you put it into the list (i.e. on the line `[grail]`).  Are you asking how to convert the `dict` back to a struct later (in which case it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673249/how-to-initialize-a-struct-from-a-dict-in-cython)?

Comment: Or are you asking store the struct inside a Python object which you then store in the list (in which case see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545875/wrapping-casting-c-struct-in-cython-to-python-class?rq=1)?